# Creating a loop to rename all sheets in workbook using excel office script

Tags: office-scripts

This is the code:

```js
/**
 * This sample renames a worksheet from "Sheet1" to "SALES".
 */
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Get a worksheet named "Sheet1".
  const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');

  // Set its name to SALES.
  sheet.setName('SALES');

  // Get a worksheet named "SALES".
  //const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('SALES');
  // Position the worksheet at the beginning of the workbook.
  sheet.setPosition(0);
}
```

Comment: What would you like to rename the various sheets to?

Comment: Any sequence naming for example sales01 sales02…

Comment: workbook.getWorksheets() will return the collection of sheets, then you can rename them in standard javascript iteration code, using the index of the loop for the sequence naming ie for(k; k < workbook.getWorksheets().length; k++) .... setName("sales"+k) kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to rename all of the sheets in the file using a convention like sales01, sales02, etc.

```
  function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let worksheets : ExcelScript.Worksheet[] = workbook.getWorksheets()
let sheetsCount: number = worksheets.length
for (let i = 0; i < sheetsCount; i++) {
  worksheets[i].setName(`SALES0${i + 1}`)
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you  beyphy , Worked pretty well. Great Help.